# Перемещение указателя в потоке или неработающий seekg

Tags: c++

Имеется файл следующего содержания:

> 1 2 3 4 5

Мне необходимо относительно текущей позиции указателя переместиться на n-ое кол-во символов вперед.
Пробую сделать так:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   ifstream file("f1");
   int c;
   int n = 2;
   file.seekg(n,file.cur);
   c = file.get();
   cout << c << endl; // "49" - 1
   return 0;
}
```

На выходе должно получится значение "50" (т.е. код символа "2"), а выходит "49" (т.е. "1") - т.е. указатель не смещается. В чем косяк?

И что удивительно, то вот таким образом выходит "50" (т.е. двойка):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   ifstream file("f1");
   int c;
   int n = 2;
   file.seekg(n);
   c = file.get();
   cout << c << endl; // "50" - 2
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Странно, а у меня выводит 50 - это код символа '2'

Comment: @Abyx, этот ко скопирован полностью без каких-либо правок. IDE - C++ Builder 6.

Comment: @sercxjo, поправил вопрос. У меня там выводит 49 ("1").

Comment: ну может быть у вас в начале файла два пробела или BOM для utf-16

Comment: @sercxjo, пробелов в начале нету, кодировка ANSI 1251. И почему тогда срабатывает прототип istream& seekg (streampos pos) ? [файл](http://rghost.ru/7wncfkbT7)

Comment: попробуйте другой компилятор

Comment: @sercxjo, так мне нужно, чтобы заработало в моём компиляторе :) Я попробовал эту же версию Билдера на другом компьютере - поведение аналогичное. Проблема получается именно в самом компиляторе?

Comment: Возможно, я не уверен

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   ifstream file("f1", file.binary); // бинарный режим решил проблему
   int c;
   int n = 2;
   file.seekg(n,file.cur);
   c = file.get();
   cout << c << endl;
   return 0;
}
```